upgrade from 4.2.6 to 5.0.6 destroyed my forms
I am using an ImageForm to upload images to my database and I store them in base64 (user's icons, only some pixels). But the update destroyed the functionality:
class CustomImageFile(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        output = [super().render(name, value)]
        try:
            output.append(self.form_instance.instance.show_picture())
        except:
            pass
        return "".join([x for x in output])

class PersonAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image_file = forms.ImageField(widget=CustomImageFile, required=False, label="picture")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["image_file"].widget.form_instance = self 

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["name", ..., "image_file"]

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["get_name", "get_picture"]    

    @admin.display(description="...")
    def get_picture(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.show_picture
        except: 
            return "... "

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.TextField("asb64", blank=True)
    
    def show_picture(self):
        try:
            return format_html(f"""<img src="{self.picture}">""")     
        except:
            return ""

I tested this with Django 4.2.6 & 4.2.13 which yields:

After an upgrade to 5.0.6:

Where there changes to ImageField? I have not yet found something in the patchnotes I could use, but would be glad for a solution.

Firstly that self.form_instance.instance.show_picture() will always throw an exception since show_picture is a property and it doesn't return any callable value. Next I don't know how this will even have worked in Django 4.2.6 since that "".join([x for x in output]) will always convert any safe string to a normal string... It might make more sense to simply ask how to get this working because this won't work in Django 4.2.6 (atleast with the code you show).

you are right, the show_picture() is not a property but a normal function.

you actually solved it: in Django 4.2.6 it is not necessary to put a format_html() around the return value of render(). After upgrading to django 5.0.6 I can now do: format_html("".join([x for x in output])) and it now works on this django version as well. If you write it as answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Not really, I knew a format_html or a mark_safe would have worked but I don't know how it would have worked without it in Django 4.2. Do note you're misusing format_html though and should instead be using a mark_safe (Using format_html without any args / kwargs is now deprecated). Feel free to answer this if you want to.

Also note that format_html(f"""<img src="{self.picture}">""") is absolutely unsafe if the value for the field directly comes from the user. An f-string is basically string interpolation. If you are absolutely sure that self.picture is a base 64 string then only can it be considered safe.
